# Getting Hyperlink from External Database

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues with getting the value or URL of a hyperlink from an external source.

I have a cell with the following formula:

```
=HYPERLINK([@[CHANGE_LINK]])
```

It gets the URL from an external data source and puts it into the cell.

In my VBA sub i have the following:

```
Dim cellRow As Integer
Dim URL As String
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets(changeSheet).Range("A1:A2000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
cellRow = 4
For Each Value1 In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    URL = Range(Value1.Address).Value '<----CANT GET URL!
    MsgBox URL
    Sheets(sheetname).Range("B" & cellRow & ":B" & cellRow).Value = "=HYPERLINK(" & URL & ",""View Change"")"
    cellRow = cellRow + 1
Next Value1
```

However, my question is. How do I get the URL of that formula into a VBA variable?

I have tried multiple ways of doing this and none seem to get the URL:

```
Range("A1:A1").value
Range("A1:A1").Address
Range("A1:A1").Formula
Range("A1:A1").Hyperlink(1)
Range("A1:A1").Hyperlink(1).Item(1)
Range("A1:A1").Hyperlinks
Range("A1:A1").Hyperlink.address
Range("A1:A1").Hyperlink.subaddress
```

**Update 27/03/2015**

I use the follow code, which should work. However it doesnt retreive the text as a string. It doesnt seem to allow me to use it in the script...No idea why..

```
Dim row As Range
Dim cellRow As Integer
Dim URL As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets(changeSheet).Range("B19:B2000")
cellRow = 4
For Each row In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    URL = row.Text <--Application doesnt like the URL parsed into the statement below:
    Sheets(sheetname).Range("B" & cellRow & ":B" & cellRow).Value = "=HYPERLINK(" & URL & ",""View Change"")" <---This is now the issue, ERROR 1004, Application or Object defined error....
    cellRow = cellRow + 1
Next row
```

Comment: Have you tried `Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address` ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that, the error message is "Script out of range", still not pulling the URL.

Comment: I see... Just tried it myself. I tried using the locals window to see what was going on and it shows 0 items even if i put a hyperlink in the cell. Hopefully someone with better relevant experience can chime in. Sorry, and good luck!

Comment: yes, hopefully. I've been trying for hours. Not sure if its due to being external in a database that it cant access it. But it should once it pulls into the Excel sheet cell. thanks anyway for your support Porcupine911 :)

Comment: What does `Range("A1").value` return?

Comment: I "msgbox"  "Range("A1").value" and comes up with blank.

Comment: `URL = Value1.Text` ?

Comment: That seems to work! - It retrieves the URL as text which is what i want. it seems that just "value1" provides the actual URL, which is weird. Surely Value1.value would return the text?  However, there is an issue, see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links are created by formulas.
So you can retrieve them by using `Formula Property`.
Now if your `URL's` are always in the form of string with qoutations, you can try below

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A2000").SpecialCell(xlCellTypeFormulas)

For Each c In r
    Msgbox Split(c.Formula, """")(1)
Next
```

This will return all your `URL's`. 
However, if it is pointing a cell or outside reference you can try `Evaluate` like this:

```
Dim f As String, myurl As String

For Each c In r
    f = c.Formula
    myurl = Evaluate(Split(Mid(f, InStr(f, "(") + 1), ")")(0))
    MsgBox myurl
Next
```

This works on formula like: `=HYPERLINK($B$1)` where `$B$1` contains the actual path.
It will return the actual `URL` stored in cell reference.
I cannot check if it will work with your case, but you can give it a try.

**Additional:**

Your formula omits the `[friendly_name]` argument, it should display the actual path on the cell.
If so, you can retrieve the `URL` with `.Value` property.
Although you mentioned it in your post, are you certain this doesn't work?

Comment: I thanks for your input, as you rightly say, i can get the formula of the cell i.e. "=HYPERLINK([@[CHANGE_LINK]])", however it cant be evaluated for some reason. I get Error 2015 when doing this: URL = Evaluate(Value1.Formula) , msgbox URL.

Answer (score 1):

So I think your fundamental problem is that in your function setting line, you need to put the URL in double quotes, so that line changes to:

```
Sheets(sheetname).Range("B" & cellRow & ":B" & cellRow).Function = "=HYPERLINK(""" & URL & """,""View Change"")"
```

Note the extra double-doublequotes around the URL variable.  The examples in the Microsoft help documentation clearly shows the URL needs be in quotes in the HYPERLINK function, and the setting of the cell abort without those quotes.

Relative to the line you tagged [URL = Range(Value1.Address).Value] as not getting the URL.  We would need to see your source data if indeed that line also has a problem.  However, in my simple debug, I added *hyperlinks* into the source data cells (not a string of a URL), and your line-of-code above worked just fine putting the URL out of the hyperlink in the cell.

Putting the ".SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" redundantly in the "For Each" statement seems unnecessary since it is already a qualifier in the "rng" variable.  Works just fine for me without it, and I did hide some source data rows in my debug test just to make sure they were skipped.